# A concise way to describe the distribution of words in a text

Tags: text-mining, descriptive-statistics

I have a text, and I count, for each distinct word, the number of times that word appears in the text.

In some texts, there are many rare words, so the distribution will have a long "tail" of words that appear once. In other texts, there are common words that usually appear more than once, so the "tail" will be shorter.

What is a standard measurement that describes this difference?

Comment: Skewness is what you want.

Comment: There are *many* ways to describe the fact that there are many words that occur ones, vs fewer words. One example would be "the proportion of the total number of different words that occur exactly once".

Comment: Have a look at Zipf's law